# Possible to repeat an if statement?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make some sort of character creation to become more familiar with Java as I'm very new to it. I want the user to be able to choose a name and then select a class. For class selection I use the scanner method, and that means that the user will have to spell their class correctly.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstTestNew {

public static void main( String args[]) {

    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner classInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Swordsman, Sorcerer, Elementalist, Assassin, Sharpshooter; // Classes
    int Level = 1;
    int Strength=1, Endurance=1, Vitality=1, Willpower=1, Luck=1, Intelligence=1; // Attributes
    int Health = Vitality*5*(Level*2); // HP = Vitality + Level
    int Mana = Willpower*10+(Level*2); // MP = Willpower + Level
    int Energy = Endurance*50+(Level*10); // NRG = Endurance + Level
    int PhysDmg = Strength*3+(Level*2); // Physical Damage
    int MagDmg = Willpower*3+(Level*2); // Magical Damage

    // Name selection
    out.println("Input your character name : ");
    String playerName = nameInput.nextLine();
    out.println("You are now to be known as "+playerName);

    // Class selection
    out.println("\nNow, what class would you like to play?\nSwordsman, Sorcerer, Elementalist, Assassin or Sharpshooter?");
    String playerClass = classInput.nextLine();

    if (playerClass.equals("Swordsman")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Swordsman!");}

    else if (playerClass.equals("Sorcerer")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Sorcerer!");}

    else if (playerClass.equals("Elementalist")){
        out.println("You chose to be an Elementalist!");}

    else if (playerClass.equals("Assassin")){
        out.println("You chose to be an Assassin!");}

    else if (playerClass.equals("Sharpshooter")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Sharpshooter!");}

    else {
        out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");}
    }
}
```

So, basically, if the user spells the class differently, I want the 'else' to be used, so they are informed of their spelling mistake, and then it repeats to the start of the if statement, so they can try again. Is this even possible to do? Maybe by using loops of some kind?

Comment: Yes, a loop is the right construct to use for this.

Comment: How do I go about constructing that loop though? I am really new to this and not really sure how to do it... :(

Comment: Google "java loop tutorial". There's *lots* of material out there.

Comment: Why don't you assign a number to each class and ask user for the number

Comment: You might also want to post this program as a question on the site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. There are a number of ways in which you could make your code better organized, easier to write/modify, and less error-prone, and people there can explain how.

Comment: @JeyesElite I would definitely post it on `codereview`, as David says. My answer has now an alternative, more flexible approach, but there are also UX issues you could address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern:

```
boolean valid;
String playerClass = "";
do
{
    valid = true; // reset each time
    // Class selection
    out.println("\nNow, what class would you like to play?\nSwordsman, Sorcerer, Elementalist, Assassin or Sharpshooter?");
    playerClass = classInput.nextLine();

    if (playerClass.equals("Swordsman")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Swordsman!");}
    else if (playerClass.equals("Sorcerer")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Sorcerer!");}
    ...
    else {
        System.out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

The loop will repeat every time the final `else` is hit as it will set `valid = false;`. You could also encapsulate this in a function, which would be better coding practice.

#### Alternative approach

For what it's worth, you could also simplify your `if` statements using a `List<String>` of options and the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method to test for valid input.

For better UX I would also consider asking them for an option number instead of a word, and if you must ask for a word then use `classInput.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase()` and compare with the words in all lower case to reduce the chance of whitespace and capitalization errors.

```
final String allOptions = "Swordsman,Sorcerer,Elementalist,Assassin,Sharpshooter";
List<String> options = Arrays.asList(allOptions.split(","));
//  construct the display message
String msg = "\nNow, what class would you like to play?\n";
// in general use a StringBuilder for this. += used for brevity only
for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) msg += options.get(i) + ", ";
msg += options.get(options.size() - 1) + "?";
```

Now your loop is as simple as:

```
boolean valid = false; 
String playerClass = "";
while (!valid)
{
    // Class selection
    out.println(msg);
    playerClass = classInput.nextLine();
    valid = options.contains(playerClass);
    if (!valid)
        System.out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
}
out.println("You chose to be a " + playerClass + "!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways:
The first way would be to have the class selection in a function wich gets called everytime the player spells the word wrong.

The other way is to create a while loop. Just create a variable with the value true, make a while loop as long as the value is true and if the word is spelled correctly the variable is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do-while loop:

```
boolean isSpelledCorrecly = true;
do {
   // get input
   ...
   else {
      out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
      isSpelledCorrecly = false;
   }     
}
while(!isSpelledCorrecly)
```

Comment: bad code: this will loop infinitely if the first choice is not a match

Comment: can you explain? it will execute only once in case of a match, or infinitely until a match is found.

Comment: Not as written. On iteration 0, assume bad input. Now the boolean is `false`. On iteration 1 assume good input, but the boolean is still `false` ∴ the loop continues indefinitely.

Comment: It's not an edge case it is the *whole point* of asking for re-input if the first input is bad!

Answer (score -1):

It is better to move that logic into a separate method and use a repetitive structure to call it back if invalid input

e.g.

```
//your logic
while(isValidClass());
//your other logic


public boolean isValidClass(){
    String playerClass = classInput.nextLine();
    boolean isValid = true;
    if (playerClass.equals("Swordsman")){
       out.println("You chose to be a Swordsman!");}
    else if (playerClass.equals("Sorcerer")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Sorcerer!");}
    else if (playerClass.equals("Elementalist")){
        out.println("You chose to be an Elementalist!");}
    else if (playerClass.equals("Assassin")){
        out.println("You chose to be an Assassin!");}
    else if (playerClass.equals("Sharpshooter")){
        out.println("You chose to be a Sharpshooter!");}
    else {
        out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: how does the original function get access to `playerClass`?

Comment: in the code there is no need f playerClass. So why to worry?

Comment: But there must be a reason for the input and so for keeping it available. Otherwise if we follow your argument to it's ultimate end we don't need to bother with any of this at all so the most efficient solution is not to even ask for the input. If you update your answer I will happily remove the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

A do-while loop seems to be a great answer to your piece of code. An easy way to control your loop is to define a bool so:

```
boolean loop=true;
//everything else that goes into your code
//...
//println where you requesto to enter the class name
do{
String playerClass = classInput.nextLine();
if (playerClass.equals("Swordsman")){
    out.println("You chose to be a Swordsman!");
    loop=false;}

else if (playerClass.equals("Sorcerer")){
    out.println("You chose to be a Sorcerer!");
    loop=false;}

else if (playerClass.equals("Elementalist")){
    out.println("You chose to be an Elementalist!");
    loop=false;}

else if (playerClass.equals("Assassin")){
    out.println("You chose to be an Assassin!");
    loop=false;}

else if (playerClass.equals("Sharpshooter")){
    out.println("You chose to be a Sharpshooter!");
    loop=false;}

else {
    out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
    }
    }while(loop);
```

Comment: this is a really verbose way to do it. Invert the boolean's meaning and you have so much less code to write

Comment: Now that I think about it you're correct @AndyBrown just inverting bool's meaning makes less code to write, changing it only in the else statement inside the loop.

Comment: Also, you can't get access to `playerClass` outside your loop with your current implementation.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick...

```
boolean incomplete = true;

while (incomplete) {
    // Class selection
    out.println("\nNow, what class would you like to play?\nSwordsman, Sorcerer, Elementalist, Assassin or Sharpshooter?");
    String playerClass = classInput.nextLine();
    switch (playerClass) {
        case "Swordsman":
            out.println("You chose to be a Swordsman!");
            incomplete = false;
            break;
        case "Sorcerer":
            out.println("You chose to be a Sorcerer!");
            incomplete = false;
            break;
        case "Elementalist":
            out.println("You chose to be an Elementalist!");
            incomplete = false;
            break;
        case "Assassin":
            out.println("You chose to be an Assassin!");
            incomplete = false;
            break;
        case "Sharpshooter":
            out.println("You chose to be a Sharpshooter!");
            incomplete = false;
            break;
        default:
            out.println("Make sure your spelling is correct.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a switch is much more efficient than a long if/else chain and should always be used in situations like this.

Comment: If you wanted to be even more efficient you could place your classes into an Enumeration and switch on the enum.

Comment: (a) `playerClass` isn't accessible outside the loop; (b) if you invert the boolean's meaning you have a lot less code to write; (c) if you want to make the code more efficient then put the options into a list and use `contains`; or (d) better still ask for a numeric option number as an input. It's a good idea to look for a different approach, but this ends up introducing/not improving a number of issues.